# Giving an alias to anonymous type property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, anonymous-types

I have 2 properties with the same name:

```
List<CustomerWithCountry> customersList = CustomerEntity.LoadCustomersSubsetForCriteria(null, 0, 100, null)
.Select(c => new { c.CODE, c.NAME, c.COUNTRY.NAME }).ToList();
```

It has a problem with c.Name and c.Country.Name having the same name.

So I try to give c.Country.Name an alias:

```
.Select(c => new { c.CODE, c.NAME, CountryName = c.COUNTRY.NAME }).ToList();
```

gives me the following error:

> Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#3>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ViewCustomersPage.CustomerWithCountry>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error should have been there without the alias as well, since you are selecting [Anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), and you are trying to assign the result of `ToList` to `List<CustomerWithCountry>`. You need to project the result to your class `CustomerWithCountry`.

So in your query it should be :

```
select (c=> new CustomerWithCountry() {.....
```

But remember if your class is coming from Entity framework or LINQ to SQL then you can't project to that type.

Answer (score 2):

create new `CustomerWithCountry` object

```
List<CustomerWithCountry> customersList =
           CustomerEntity.LoadCustomersSubsetForCriteria(null, 0, 100, null)
              .Select(c => new CustomerWithCountry{ 
                        CODE= c.CODE, 
                        NAME= c.NAME, 
                        CountryName = c.COUNTRY.NAME })
              .ToList();
```